# Что такое "продел"?

Tags: этимология

Почему некоторые виды круп называются "продел"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Продел - от глагола проделать(проделывать). 
У Даля: ПРОДЕЛЫВАТЬ, проделать в чем дыру, просверлить; проделать окно, дверь, пробить, прорубить. | **Проделывать крупу**, молоть, зернить, крупить, драть

Продел - не цельное зерно, а измельченное.

Comment: У Даля через чур просто...  Убивается такое толкование одним Каверзным  вопросом, проделывать дырку в чем? Или чем?  Вот если нитку продел, вдел, это значит воткнул в ушко иголки. А еще продевают в дырку.

Как в зерне можно дырку пробуравить, непонятно. 
А вот если делить зерно на части, получатся доли. То есть этимология от слова делить, поделить.
Делать и делить--разные вещи, хотя можно и разделать.

Comment: Всё правильно, кроме "через чур" и "Каверзным". Однако во всех справочниках у этого слова нет приставки, а только корень "продел". Видимо, приставка так срослась с "дел", что слилась в один корень.

Answer (score 0):

**продел,** -а, *м. Спец*. Название крупы (гречневой, рисовой и др.), ядра которой расколоты на крупные или мелкие части.
*Рисовый **продел**. Мелкий гречневый **продел**. Продельная крупа.*

Словарь русского языка в четырех томах, том III, 1959.
[спец. - специальный термин]

**Проделка** или **продел** (от проделывать) - муж., *проем, **проруб**, пробитое в чем отверстие.*
[**проделывать; продел**](https://slovar.cc/rus/dal/571550.html)

**Гречка** различается по целости зерна - **ядрица** (цельное зерно), **продел** (зерно с нарушенной структурой), **смоленская крупа** (сильно измельченные зерна), гречневая **мука**.
[**Крупы. Гречневая (продел)**](http://edimka.ru/prod173)